# Make sure Bin File Permissions Don't Change When Updated Via Git on Plesk

Tags: git, cakephp, permissions, plesk

I have a web project on Plesk that I am using Git to update and develop. One of the directories is a bin file that contains a file called cake. Its part of the CakePHP framework which you can learn more about going to the [CakePHP website](https://cakephp.org/). I use commands as part of my development process. Most importantly I use the CakePHP migration's plugin to run commands like `bin/cake migrations migrate`. This works fine without any problems on my local development environment which is running on Windows 10 with XAMPP as my development server.

When I try to run the commands remotely so that I can easily deploy needed DB changes, get the status of the migration, or clear a cache I find that if I have pushed a commit out to the remote server I always have to manually change the permission of the bin/cake file so that I can execute it. I would like to stop doing this as it is annoying. Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set additional deployment actions in the *Repository settings* menu, in Plesk's Git extension.

It accepts shell commands, so it seems appropriate for the scenario you are dealing with.

You could also add the bin file to .gitignore, but it will keep out of version control (obviously). You'll have to update it manually when it changes.